# Stripe API key missing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, stripe-payments

We're facing a problem with Stripe API keys. What I've done so far is:

- set environment/*.rb to utilise appropriate Stripe keys using constants
- created a `config/initializers/stripe.rb` with the line `Stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET`
- using the rails console, both `STRIPE_PUBLIC` and `STRIPE_SECRET` constants are set and visible. `STRIPE_PUBLIC => "pk_test_xxxxxxxxx"`

However, once these things are in place, making a call to Stripe's API using the browser results in:

```
Stripe::AuthenticationError in some_controller#some_action

No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.
```

Using the web-console gem, we can tell that `STRIPE_SECRET` and `STRIPE_PUBLIC` are nil in the website. But every time we run `rails console` we get our keys from our constants.

Comment: are you running both in the same environment? maybe you've added the keys to the "environments/development.rb" but not to "environments/production.rb"?

Comment: `environments/production.rb` has `STRIPE_SECRET = ENV['LIVE_STRIPE_SECRET']` and a _PUBLIC verions.

`environments/development.rb` and `environements/test.rb` both have `STRIPE_SECRET = ENV['TEST_STRIPE_SECRET']` and a _PUBLIC version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue. The terminal running rails server had been opened since before the environment variables had been set.

Therefore, running source ~/.bashrc (for me) or using a new terminal worked for me.

Thank you, sincerely, to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are encountering is happening because if the way you are setting the key.

You cannot expect something you set using the rails console to be available to the web application. The Rails console started up as its own unique process that does not share anything with the web process started and accessed by the browser.

If you want the key to be available to the web application try setting it as an environment variable and reading it accordingly in your stripe.rb file

Comment: We are not setting the API key through the `rails console`. The line that sets the api key is `Stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET`, and the line that sets STRIPE_SECRET will depend on the environment. So `environments/development.rb` has the line `STRIPE_SECRET = ENV['TEST_STRIPE_SECRET']`

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the rails server to make these values available to the rails app since the changes were made in the initializers directory.